# How do I implement a MongoDB Bson formatter in Web API 2?

Tags: json, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 project and my `WebApiConfig` looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config
            .MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        config
            .Formatters
            .JsonFormatter
            .SupportedMediaTypes
            .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I want the json to be parsed 'Mongo DB style' so automatically get serialization of ObjectIDs, so I can use attributes like `[BsonElement("name")]` on properties in my model classes and so on.

I looked around and found this article http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/09/30/custom-serialization-with-json-net-webapi-and-bsondocument.aspx but it seems a bit outdated and I cannot get it to work.

I'm pretty stuck for the moment, help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement and register a custom media formatter. Basically, you need to do this:

- derive a class from `MediaTypeFormatter` (asynchronous read/write implementation)  or `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter` (synchronous read/write implemetation)

  - declare the supported MIME type for BSON format in the class constructor
  - implement `CanWriteType` + `WriteToStream` and/or  `CanreadType` + `ReadFromStream`
- register the media formatter class in Web API configuration

Take into account that the formatter will be used:

- to parse the received data, when the media format is specified in `Content-Type` header (this is the Read part of your implementation)
- to serialize the returned object when the media format is specified with `Accept` header (this is the write part of your implementation)

You can have a look at these samples, or google for "Web API custom media formatters" to get more info and samples:

- [Media Formatters in ASP.NET Web API 2. Sample of csv formatter.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters)
- [Implementing Custom Media Formatters in ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559378/Implementing-Custom-Media-Formatters-in-ASP-NET-We)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Those are good pointers. But have you found an existing implementation? Googled it plenty, but came up with nothing. I can't be the first one that need this... =)

Comment: I don't know of any implementation. However, there's an exisintg implementation of BSON (de)serializer: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/ If you use it, the implementation of your custom formatter is nearly trivial.